# debian:jessie docker image does not install Nginx with HTTP/2 support

Tags: docker, nginx, debian, debian-jessie

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ARG ENV_APP
ARG ENV_SMF

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx

ADD conf.d/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
ADD conf.d/nginx.${ENV_SMF}.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/symfony.conf

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/symfony.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/symfony \
&& rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server grozissaviems_${ENV_APP}_php:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

By default this line `apt-get install -y nginx` installs nginx:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
```

Now, I need HTTP/2 enabled, but this nginx version is too old and does not support it.
If I run typical check `curl -I -L https://stg.grozissaviems.lt --insecure`, the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.21.1
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2022 11:42:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.34
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 06 Apr 2022 11:42:20 GMT
Link: </build/images/landing_1350.webp>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_800.webp>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_1350.webp>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_1350.png>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_800.png>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_1350.png>; rel="preload"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

Just to be sure I tried running same command from another image that has the newer nginx version `1.19.6` and the output is:

```
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx/1.21.1
date: Wed, 06 Apr 2022 11:42:31 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.34
cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
pragma: no-cache
expires: Wed, 06 Apr 2022 11:42:31 GMT
link: </build/images/landing_1350.webp>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_800.webp>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_1350.webp>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_1350.png>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_800.png>; rel="preload",</build/images/landing_1350.png>; rel="preload"
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```

I assume the issue if of nginx being old. How can I fix it? I cannot find a way to upgrade (preferable install) newer nginx version when running docker.

P.S. `apt-get update && apt-get-upgrade` does not upgrade nginx version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem lately and found out that the LTS for Debian 8 "Jessie" has ended on June 30, 2020, which is too old for me.

I changed to use the [official Nginx Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

Note that `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` was no longer exist and default config was changed to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

In your case, it will become

```
FROM nginx:1.22

ARG ENV_APP
ARG ENV_SMF

ADD conf.d/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
ADD conf.d/nginx.${ENV_SMF}.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/symfony.conf

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/symfony.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/symfony.conf \
&& rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server grozissaviems_${ENV_APP}_php:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["nginx"]
```